# Invoking a Runtime method from within Codename One

Tags: java, command-line, runtime, codenameone

I am getting a compilation error to my code in StateMachine.java class in a Codename One project:

```
error: cannot find symbol
              getRuntime().
symbol:   method exec(String)
location: class Runtime
```

the full statement is;

```
try {    
    Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd.exe /c start dir ");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Print this");
}
```

and is running fine in a plain Java project.

What am i missing?

//===============================================

ADD: ..and to

```
try {
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c dir A*");
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Print this");
}
```

I'm also getting an compiler error saying

```
error: cannot find symbol
     Process 
symbol:   class Process
location: class StateMachine
```

seems to be blocking the OS/backend reach-- but how, what's the "mentality" behind?

Comment: Are you developing on Eclipse with a Codename One plugin? It seems like it's not providing the compiler with the JDK libs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We don't support `Runtime.exec` and it will obviously not work on a mobile phone where you have neither cmd nor access to other processes running on the device due to process isolation. E.g. iOS maintains a private file system per process so sharing files becomes a problem.

You can use `Display.getInstance().execute()` to run things like the browser but obviously cmd will never work on a device regardless of the technology you choose.

Comment: In the ant task. We don't "block it" it just won't work, since the iOS VM or even the Android VM don't really have it.